# How to implement classes with references to each other?

Tags: c++, circular-reference

I'm new to C++ programming, so maybe you'd find my question too stupid. Sorry about that, but I'd like to know how to implement this Java-style structure:

```
#include "B";
class A {
   B objB;
}
---
#include "A";
class B {
   A objA;
}
```

The compiler going crazy trying to understand this code. Could you please advise me about a possible solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is illegal in C++ and the compiler is right to reject it.  The problem is that if you have a concrete object of type A inside of an object of type B and vice-versa, then there is no meaningful definition of the size of either object.  In particular, objects in C++ must each be at least one byte in size.  Therefore, given an object of type A (call it `a`), there must be one byte of storage for `a`, `a.objB.objA`, `a.objB.objA.objB.objA`, etc.  In fact, you'd need infinite storage space, because there's always an object nested further inside of these objects!

To fix this, you'll want to change this so that you're storing *pointers* to objects of type B and A in A and B, respectively.  This breaks the chain because while an `A*` pointer *points* to an `A` object, the pointer itself isn't an `A` object and thus uses only four bytes.  Once you have this, you can use forward declarations to declare these pointers.  For example:

File: A.h:

```
class B;
class A {
     B* objB;
};
```

File: B.h:

```
class A;
class B {
     A* objA;
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. that was really helpful to get understanding.

Comment: @Kid24- Glad to help!  Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answers your question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward-declare

```
class B;
```

before you define class A, then continue as before. That would work for references, but not for objects like this, since you can't really have an object implicitly contain itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an object `B` inside an object `A` which itself is inside an object `B`. Recursively you would never be able to construct the object because it has infinite recursion.

What you can do:

```
#include "B"
class A {
    B *objB;
}

#include "A"
class B {
    A objA
}
```

Comment: That won't actually work, if the headers are properly surrounded by include guards.

Comment: @GMan: Of course. And maybe a forward class declaration in each of the included files.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing this is to consider a single source file, having included A.H or B.H "first". [ "first" being quoted given the likely confusion there as well.]

```
class A {
   B objB;
}
class B {
   A objA;
}
```

How can this make sense? We cannot possibly define A before we know B and we cannot define B before we know A. Hence the solution via indirection as noted by others.